# How to save key value pair in mongoose correctly

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I would like to save this example data in my mongodb. But i don't know how to achieve this and i don't know how to declare the type of the object i'm saving. The Citys should have a `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` with `ref: 'Country'`

How would a script to save data in this format look like and how would the model look like?

**citys**

```
{
    name: Paris,
    number: 001,
    country: 5c1292439da9b851a833cbba
}
{
    name: Berlin,
    number: 002,
    country: 5c1292439da9b851a833aabc
}
...
```

**countrys**

```
{
    id: 5c1292439da9b851a833cbba
    name: France
    number: 001
}
{
    id: 5c1292439da9b851a833aabc
    name: Germany
    number: 002
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Instead of two collections, Take advantage of mongodb's  embedded collection(document).

    country :  [{
           name: France,
           number: 001,
           cities : [{
                     name: Paris,
                     number: P001
                   },{
                     name: Lyon,
                     number : P002,
                    }]

    },{
           name: Germany,
           number: 002,
           cities : [{
                     name: Berlin,
                     number: G001
                   },{
                     name: Hamburg,
                     number : G002,
                    }]

    }]

Schema - 

    var mongoose  = require('mongoose'),
        Schema    = mongoose.Schema;

    var Country= new Schema({
      name: String,
      number: Number,
      cities : [{
               name : String,`enter code here`
               number : String
               }]
    });

mongoose.model('Country', Country);

Query - 
 var obj = {
           name : "Hamburg",
           number : "G002"
          };
 country.update({name: "France"},
                { $push :  { cities: obj}},
                function(err,result){})

Hope this helps
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking to create a Schema in Nodejs [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/mongoose) has a good write up on the subject.

Yours could look like:

```js
var mongoose  = require('mongoose'),
    Schema    = mongoose.Schema;

var City = new Schema({
  name: String,
  number: Number,
  country: String
});

mongoose.model('City', City);
```